# Computer slow when there is over 8GB RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance

My motherboard is a Sapphire pure black X58, with 6 ram slots ( tri-channel ) and 3x 2GB G.Skill PC12800 PI series on them, and when I received for free 6x 2BG G.skill PC12800 NQ series I wanted to upgrade my system.
But the problem is that when I plugged my memory everything seemed a lot slower, the UC was at 20-30% on idle, launching any single application would make it 100% UC.

So I've tried removing modules one by one, and plugged them them separately, and it seems that, for every combination, when I have more than 4 DIMM's plugged everything goes slow.

I've moved the 4th module into every empty slot so they should all work. And all the RAM work as well when they are only three.

I've also tried to mix them with 2x 2GB G.Skill PC10600 NT series (those are dual channel), with the same results.

Every module has been tested on another computer two by two, and they all seemed to work fine.

I've also formatted my drive and reinstalled windows, same thing happens.

There is no update for the BIOS on Sapphire's site.

I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/402333/computer-slow-after-installing-32gb-ram) that activating the onboard video card could solve the problem, but I don't have one, so there's that :D

And finally I've looked into the memory voltages and timings, so far the voltages seem normal but i'm confused by the timings, I'm not sure if my motherboard is adjusting well or not. So I have multiple reports from CPU-Z (I'll join them ), for every combination tested.

Here are the motherboard's timings from CPU-Z (only the two first combinations works):
3x NQ: 7-7-7-20
3x PI + 1x NQ: 8-8-8-20

3x PI + 2x NT: 8-8-8-20
3x NQ + 2x NT: 7-7-7-20
3x PI + 3x NQ: 8-8-8-20

It looks like they don't match the memories timings at all, am I missing something here?

I've tried forcing XMP Profile with 3x NQ's and 3x PI's once and I got a nice BSOD :)

Anybody have an idea on this? 
thanks :)

My system:

CPU: Intel i7 930 @ 2.8GHz
Motherboard: Sapphire Pure Black X58 (socket 1366) ( [specs](http://sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?pid=1045))

RAM:
-  3x 2GB G.Skill PC12800 PI series 8-8-8-21 @1.65v
-  6x 2GB G.Skill PC12800 NQ series 9-9-9-24 @1.5v
-  2x 2GB G.Skill PC10600 NT series 9-9-9-24 @1.5v

GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT 640
Two Hitachi HDD ( 750GB and 2To), no SSD
OS: Windows 7 64bit

Full CPU-Z reports:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8rfXD0XQoSxaFBsZUZselhRQkU&usp=sharing

PS: sorry English is not my native language, tell me if something is unclear ^^

Comment: Set all your BIOS memory timings and voltages to auto.

Comment: They're already on auto, I was wondering if the motherboard took the good values.

Comment: Tried resetting your mobo by removing the CMOS battery?